# .NET IoC / Repository pattern boilerplate

Tags: c#, .net

I've scoured the net and can't seem to find a boilerplate/bootstrapper/template for an IoC (preferrably Unity) with generic repository pattern out there. Obviously I've developed a system with the same architecture before - but throwing it out there if there's a simple (preferrably NuGet) solution of achieving my reference architecture quickly that I'm not aware of?

The only thing I've found is: https://github.com/nickbreslin/Unity-Boilerplate which doesn't seem to be much help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there's some discussion regarding generic repositories being unnecessary abstraction in some cases: http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton. In my personal opinion, you needed generic repositories because linq2sql was not easy mockable, using NHibernate or EF there's no point.

Comment: I'll be using EF, but I've found generic repositories just easy to work with - it does add that extra layer of abstraction but it also adds a unification to all my calls. This actually saved me a hell of a lot of time on a certain project that required a log on every specific EF Update.

Comment: Windsor Castle framework has some really amazing integration with NHibernate

Comment: It most certainly does, but I'm not 100% sure I'm making my question clear - is there just any form of .NET project template that sets this up for you? Originally it took me a good hour or so otherwise to combine all the pieces.

Comment: How much development time do you spend creating that code for a new project? You are talking about code which takes less than an hour to hand-roll.

Comment: I'm getting this idea from DurandalJS - it took me 10 seconds to have a fully-fledged MVVM framework, where normally it would have taken an hour. It's more a query than anything .

Comment: @ChrisDixon: to log calls you use event listeners in NHibernate, http://ayende.com/blog/3987/nhibernate-ipreupdateeventlistener-ipreinserteventlistener

Comment: Have you tried microsoft enterprise library ? http://unity.codeplex.com/